# Curl and Postman giving different response?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, curl, postman

I am writing API in node.js.

url http://localhost:8000/api/request?connId=19&timeout=8000

when I call above API from **Postman** then it takes 8 seconds to give the response. same as expected.

but when call this from **curl** it gives output instantly.

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/request?connId=19&timeout=8000
```

Code is:

```
app.get('/api/request', ( req, res ) => {

    let timeoutID = null;   // return by setTimeout
    let starttime = null;   // time when request is begin
    const time = req.query.timeout;     // time send by client
    const connId = req.query.connId;    // id send by client

    // checking client data is valid or not
    if ( typeof(connId) !== undefined && typeof(time) !== undefined ) {

        starttime = new Date();     // get current time
        starttime = starttime.setMilliseconds(starttime.getMilliseconds()); // convert into millisecon
        // initiate setTimeout
        timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
            // remove that element from global array which reqest has been complted
            removeByAttr(timeout, 'connId', connId);
            // res.send({ status: "ok"});       // send response

        }, time);
        // initiate setInterval
        const setInv = setInterval(() => {
            // check timeout [] conatin the current request
            const arrLength = timeout.length && timeout.filter(({ connId }) => req.query.connId === connId).length;

            if ( arrLength === 0 ) {
                res.send({ status: "ok"}); // send response
                clearInterval(setInv);      // clear/destroy current Interval
            }

        }, 80);

        // insert the current request into global [] timeout
        timeout.push({
            connId,
            time,
            timeoutID,
            starttime,
            'endtime': +starttime + +time
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: try change the `const` keyword to `let` ?

Comment: changing all const into let is not working

Comment: Postman gets special cross-domain privileges. Could be security is slowing it down?

Comment: @KolobCanyon but I write API that must send the response after given time. there is no security apply yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found from your code and [curl tutorial that](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Spec) When you GET a endpoint with curl your command should be like this:

`curl "http://localhost:8000/api/request?connId=19&timeout=8000"`

Without double inverted comma in url, `console.log(req.query)` will result in `{ connId: '19' }` which is causing the problem.